# How can I change the Header Style?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, fancyhdr

I want my Header in this style like the Screenshot.[image]I use this dokumentclass  `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside, BCOR5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}` and use the`\usepackage{fancyhdr}` package and if I set the `\pagestyle{}`nothing happens.

How can set this Header style ?

Comment: Where should the page number be on chapter pages? What should be in the header if there is no section entry yet? If more than one section start on a page - which one should go to the header, the first or the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside, BCOR=5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{\thesection\autodot\quad}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\ihead{\rightmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1-13]
\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Version using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside, BCOR=5mm, DIV=12]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
    {\markboth
        {\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapappifchapterprefix{~}\thechapter\quad}{} #1}
        {\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapappifchapterprefix{~}\thechapter\quad}{} #1}%
    }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]
    {\markright{\ifnumbered{section}{\thesection\quad}{}#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\ifstr{\rightmark}{}{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1-13]
\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum
\addsec{Unnumbered Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I forget to say, that I have to using the package `fancyhdr` because it is a default template from my university, but I want to change the header style and is allowed.

Comment: See my updated answer.